# need some guidance in dialog box implementation

Tags: jquery-ui, cakephp, jquery, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have a cakephp view (index.ctp) where I have edit button. On button edit I want the jquery dialog box open with what i have in edit.ctp. (Currently if I go to edit.ctp, it works fine but I am trying to use model / dialog box so the user stays on same page)

This is what I have in my index.ctp

```
    <td>

                <?php echo $this->Html->link($team['Company']['name'], array('action' => 'edit_reload','team_id'=>$team['Team']['id']), array('id'=>"dialog_link", 'class'=>"ui-state-default ui-corner-all"));?>

            </td>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">


</div>
```

Now when the link clicked I want to show the edit_reload.ctp contents here. I am totally exhausted so any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a separate JS file write the following code and add your values to the variables and include the JS file in your .ctp file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $myWindow = $('#dialog');
    //instantiate the dialog
$myWindow.dialog({ height: 250,
        width: 200,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        autoOpen:false,
        title:'',
        overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'}
});
    $J("#dialog_link").click( showDialog );
    });// end (document).ready


  var showDialog = function() {
    var team_id = '';
    var url     = '/controller/action/' + team_id;//Apply path to controller, action
    $.post(url, function(res) {
    $myWindow.dialog({
    title:'Give Title'
});
    $('#dialog').html(res);
    $myWindow.show();
    });
  }
```

In .ctp file use the link as follows-

```
echo $this->Html->link($team['Company']['name'],'#', array('id'=>"dialog_link", 'class'=>"ui-state-default ui-corner-all"));
```

I have show you an example.You can also write the js code in the .ctp file also.